# R: What is the difference between ANCOVA and drop1?

Tags: r, ancova

In one of the slides of a statistics course that I followed the following about using drop1 or ANCOVA is stated.

> Using drop1 the p-values shown are p-values for deleting one variable at a time from the full model, whereas the p-values in the output of anova are sequential, as in a step-up strategy. This problem does not arise in ANOVA or linear regression, only in ANCOVA and mixed models.)

I looked at it for 20 minutes, and cannot understand that if this is true why someone would still use the command `anova()` in R anyway.

Does anyone have an idea?

The reason why I ask this question here is because the subject was given a few months ago.

Comment: What is the "problem" that does not arise in ANOVA or linear regression? I think perhaps you left out some key context.

Comment: I don't know either.

But I guess the problem that ANOVA or lin. reg. do not have is that they have a step-up strategy? I guess that is what it says.

Comment: By using `drop1` you imply that dropping variables from a model is a good thing.  Instead, think about what hypothesis you want to test in the context of ANCOVA, and go and test it using the appropriate contrast within the context of the full model.  There are some equivalences to this in the normal case but dropping variables from the model is an inefficient way to proceed even when correct.